# Can I count pre-funded project money as reimbursement?

Tags: united-states, income-tax, reimbursement

I'm a researcher and won a grant a year ago to do a project. But, for reasons far too aggravating to get into, the university has been really dragging its feet on actually letting me spend the money they awarded me.

With the end of the fiscal year approaching, that money has to get spent or it goes away. The new plan is to have them just pay me the money as income, and then bankroll the project myself.

I've been avoiding this option because this presumably means I need to pay income taxes on the money, and thus do the project with a big budget cut. However, can I claim this as being a reimbursement, and thus omit it from my reported income? The university will likely withhold income taxes on the funds, so it seems unlikely that I could actually do this. But is this a realistic thing to do? Or am I grasping at straws?

Comment: Why do you think the university will withhold income taxes?  Will the university be paying you as an employee?

Comment: I'd be paid as a "special consultant", which typically works through the payroll system.

Comment: It's one thing to be paid through the payroll system, it's another to be paid as an employee.  A consultant is typically paid a gross amount with reporting performed via 1099, an employee is typically paid a net amount with reporting performed via W2.  A W2 employee also has infinitely more employment rights than a 1099 contractor/consultant.

Comment: I believe I count as an employee for this purpose. In the past, at least, "special consultant" pay I have received has been reported on my W2.